# Azure B2C - IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, daemon

I have a .net core Api and a Spa application connecting to the Api. Everything works fine. Now I want to authenticate to the Api from a CLI using a client secret. I use get the token using `AcquireTokenForClient` but when I send the request to Api I get a error:
`=> 08:46:30.130 +03:00 [Information] Failed to validate the token. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key:kid: 'nOo3ZDrODXEK1jKWhXslHR_KXEq'.`

Configuration for API is

````
    "Instance": "https://xxx.b2clogin.com", 
    "ClientId": "CLIENTID",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "ID",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_Reset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_EditProfile", // Optional profile editing policy
  },

and the configuration for CLI application

{
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}",
  "Tenant": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "ID",
  "ClientId": "CLICLIENTID",
  "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
  "ClientSecret": "secret",
  "TodoListBaseAddress": "http://localhost:5000",
  "TodoListScope": "api://APICLIENTID/.default"
}```


Any idea?
````

Comment: Could you share the code for getting the token and sending the request to Api?

Comment: When you created the app registration for the CLI App - make sure to choose the "type" as "Accounts in this organisational directory only".

Comment: @PamelaPeng
I'm using the code from sample code provided by MS in this GitHub project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi. The only difference I can see is that my API is configured a bit different: The instance is https://***.b2clogin.com" instead of "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
I've checked the configuration. It is Accounts in this organizational directory only (*** only - Single tenant)